# If Not Switching When In Environment

Tags: tables, environments, conditionals

I have the following environment to create an invoice. It works perfectly except that the rows do not switch between light and dark gray (they stay light) so I assume that `\iflight` is staying true. If I change the inital `\lighttrue` command to `\lightfalse` they only stay the darker gray. Either way they are not alternating. I tried a similar command not in an environment and it worked. What's causing this to not switch?

```
\newcounter{total}
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\newif\iflight
\newenvironment{invoice}[1]{%
  \setcounter{total}{0}
  \lighttrue
  \newcommand*{\additem}[3]{\noalign{\addtocounter{total}{{##2*100}+##3}}\iflight\rowcolor{black!5!white}\lightfalse\else\rowcolor{black!10!white}\lighttrue\fi ##1 && ##2.##3 \\}%
  \textbf{Invoice no.\ #1}

  \tabularx{\linewidth}{Xrr}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{black!20!white}\textbf{Desciption} && \textbf{Amount}\\
  \hline
}{%
  \hline
  \noalign{\setcounter{a}{\value{total}/100}}
  \noalign{\setcounter{b}{\value{total}-\value{a}*100}}
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{TOTAL:}} & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \textdollar & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \arabic{a}.\ifnum\value{b}<10 0\fi\arabic{b} \\
  \endtabularx\par
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since table `cells` are treated as `TeX` groups, toggling a conditional defined with `\newif` remains local in the group, i.e. `\lighttrue` will stick to that cell and the next cell (or row) is unaware of the change.

In order to activate the change globally a `\global\lighttrue` or `\global\lightfalse` must be applied.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{total}

\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\newif\iflight
\newenvironment{invoice}[1]{%
  \setcounter{total}{0}
  \lighttrue
  \newcommand*{\additem}[3]{\noalign{\addtocounter{total}{{##2*100}+##3}}\iflight\rowcolor{black!5!white}\global\lightfalse\else\rowcolor{black!10!white}\global\lighttrue\fi ##1 && ##2.##3 \\}%
  \textbf{Invoice no.\ #1}

  \tabularx{\linewidth}{Xrr}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{black!20!white}\textbf{Desciption} && \textbf{Amount}\\
  \hline
}{%
  \hline
  \noalign{\setcounter{a}{\value{total}/100}}
  \noalign{\setcounter{b}{\value{total}-\value{a}*100}}
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{TOTAL:}} & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \textdollar & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \arabic{a}.\ifnum\value{b}<10 0\fi\arabic{b} \\
  \endtabularx\par
}


\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}{42}
  \additem{Data collection}{1500}{00}
  \additem{LaTeX book}{50000}{00}
  \additem{Answer on TeX.SX}{10000000}{00}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I sure hope I don't owe you $10000000 for that answer, but thank you once again! :)

Comment: @cabellicar123 ;-) The next answer will cost even more, but there's an overflow then ;-)